# Tkinter image placement

Tags: python, tkinter

I have trouble placing my text where I want. In the following code, my image is placed in the middle of the screen, which is what I want, but my text is at the very botton of the screen, but I want them to be together at the middle.

[image]
Here is what it displays.

```
from tkinter import *

fenetre = Tk()

width = 350
height = 299
image = PhotoImage(file="carre.png")
canvas = Canvas(fenetre, width=width, height=height, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.create_image(width/2, height/2, image=image, anchor=CENTER)
canvas.pack(expand=YES)
entree = Entry(fenetre, font=("sans-serif",20))
entree.pack()
bouton = Button(fenetre, text="CALCULER", font=("sans-serif",20), fg = "black") # fg = foreground
bouton.pack()
bouton.bind("<Button-1>")

fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"my image is placed in the middle of the screen"_ - it doesn't look like it's in the middle to me. It's centered horizontally, but not vertically. Just to be clear, you like where the canvas and image is, and only want to change the entry and label to be immediately  below the canvas?

Comment: One suggestion I have is to give your canvas a distinct color while you're trying to solve this problem. It will make the problem easier to see -- that the canvas it taking up the majority of the window.

Comment: I didn't take the whole screen, but it is in the middle thanks to the "expand=YES".  And yes i like it when it is centered and i want the entry, label, and button to be below the canvas

Comment: I added a background color to the canvas and we can only see a little line above the image, like 1 pixel thick @BryanOakley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have used `expand=YES` for the canvas. That means that all extra space in the window will be allocated to the canvas, even if the canvas doesn't use it. This causes any widgets packed below the canvas to be pushed all of the way to the bottom of the window.

It's hard to say what the right solution is, since it's unclear what other widgets might be in the same window, and what behavior you want when the window is resized.

The simplest solution is to remove `expand=YES`. That will cause `pack` to use as little space as necessary for the canvas. Then, when you pack the entry and text they will be right up against the bottom of the canvas. All extra space will be allocated below the button.

Another solution would be to put the canvas, entry, and widget in a frame rather than directly in the root. Then, you can use `pack`, `place`, or `grid` to center that frame in the window.